# Java encoding conversion between rest json and properties file

Tags: java, character-encoding, mule

I have a Latin 1 character in my properties file:

```
Privé vervoer
```

Properties file is stored using UTF-8. This caused problems and é was returned in a garbled way to the UI(separate js application).
I understand why that happened. By default, properties files are treated as ISO-8859-1. So, as commonly recommended, I changed é to its Unicode escaped representation - \u00E9.
Now, everything works like a charm, but I'm still confused. Java will treat this char as a ISO-8859-1 encoded. It's cool. But then when this same String is returned to the UI, it should be UTF-8 encoded, because that is what UI expects(`Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and `charset="utf-8"` meta tag).

I'm still not able to understand when the conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 happening.

Is it needed at all if the character is Unicode escaped? Maybe escaped characters will always be properly displayed based on the underlying application/OS?

My stack: Mule ESB, Java 8, Spring 4, Angular-based UI and nodejs gateway in the middle.

Comment: Your confusion is caused by the misunderstand of *"Java will treat this char as a ISO-8859-1 encoded"*. That is wrong. Java will treat ``\u00E9`` as a Unicode Escape sequence, for the [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE' (U+00E9)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm) (`é`). There is no conversion *from* `ISO-8859-1`. There *is* a conversion *to* `UTF-8` from Java's internal representation of a String (UTF-16), which happens because you defined result to be `charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character encoding consists in transforming characters into sequences of bytes. This is necessary when you write to a file, or to the network.

Similarly, when you read characters from a file or the network, you actually read bytes, and the sequences of bytes are decoded to characters.

The Properties class, when it reads from a file, expects that file to contain ISO_8859_1-encoded characters, i.e. bytes that have been obtained by encoding characters with ISO_8859_1. It thus reads the bytes from the file, decodes them using ISO_8859_1, and stores them as key-value pairs of Strings (which contain characters).

When you write those characters to the network, those characters are then transformed into bytes again, and you're of course not forced to use the same encoding as the one used for the properties file. So you can choose UTF_8 instead, if you prefer.

ISO_8859_1 was a stupid (IMO) choice for properties files, especially considering they're used for resource bundles, containing messages translated in many languages. Indeed, ISO_8859_1 only supports 256 characters (not all printable), and not the entire Unicode set. UTF-8 would have been a much better choice. Your specific character, (`é`), is supported by ISO_8859_1, so you actually don't have to escape it. But had you stored cyrillic, arabic or other kinds of non-lating characters in the file, then you would have had to escape these into `\uxxxx` sequences of characters (themselves containing only characters that can be encoded with ISO_8859_1: `\`, `u`, and digits)

Comment: Thanks, JB! That is very clear now. I know ISO-8859-1 supports eacute, but it won't work for me, because, based on your explanation, the bytes stored in files will always be intact. Creating a string from them is just a matter of representation. My REST response will be UTF-8. My byte sequence is ISO-8859-1(to be more precise it's CP-1252, but it's identical when it comes to Latin 1). So, without explicit transformation such Latin chars will never look Ok on the UI.